# How to make a PHP function triggered automatically at a user defined time

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am developing an internal system for a company with `PHP` using `Zend` framework. I need one of its functions to execute on a time specified by user.

My research on this matter found me several ways of doing this using `CPanel` `Cron` jobs and setting up scheduled tasks on the server. But in this scenario, I don't have a `CPanel` and I already use scheduled tasks. But my challenge is to provide an interface for the user to specify the time to trigger the function.

Any help on this is very much appreciated!! :-)

Comment: Create a simple form for the user to pick the task and time. In the background, edit the cron file directly. For new tasks it's as easy as adding a new line, for removing and updating you'll have to do some parsing. But it should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might store a 'job' in the database [ through the interface you have to provide ], and in Cron just execute script [ for example every minute ] that checks if there are any pending jobs and if their start_date is > now(). If so, execute it, otherwise do nothing. Don't forget to mark them as complete to avoid running them many times:)

Comment: Nice one my friend! :-) Thank you for your help!!